# I need to make a interface with + and - buttons, when you press + and - the lower part of the interface haves to changue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

i am creating a Football results viewer for android. I need a special interface, with this

"- button" "Round number" "+ button"

"results list of that Round number"

there is a android view/widget that solves this problem? or how i can implement it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create `RelativeLayout` with 2 buttons 1 textView and 1 ListView.

Then put data to the listview. There are tons of example on the need how to provide the listview with data.